# Where can I learn about EF migration feature that recurses into referenced types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I just ran into a feature of code first migrations that I didn't realize was there and that's pretty much because everything I know about it comes from a few getting started blog posts.

Is there any more in-depth info on the following behavior (which I find pretty cool because it seems that I can combine it with AutoMapper to simply my web service ETL life)?

For example I have:

```
public class foo
{
  [Key]
  public int id { get; set; }
  public bar { get; set; }
}

public class bar
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Then I run the migration commands:

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration FirstMigration
```

And  I get:

```
public partial class FirstMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.foos",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    name = c.String(),
                    bar_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    bar_name = c.String(),
                })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);
    }
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.foos");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check these two blog posts. They will give you overview of migrations features:

- [Automatic migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)
- [Code based migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C# expert and it might be a typo but isn't a property name missing in the foo class for the bar navigation property?